# What is the alternative to etc/systemd/system in MAC?

Tags: macos

I am trying to create Prometheus alert manager as a service, so I was looking at one of the tutorial where they create alert manager service in Linux in etc/systemd/system/alertmanager.service. I was wondering what the alternative path be in MAC? In MAC, I cant find /etc/systemd/system, I can go until /etc but there is no systemd under that folder.My goal is whenever I start my alert manager it should go to this service file under /etc/systemd/system and execute the rules in yaml file.

vi /etc/systemd/system/alertmanager.service

[image]

Please let me know where could I go and create my service file in MAC

Comment: I'd recommend you ask in a forum dedicated to MAC's - clearly MAC's don't use systemd, so, the way to achieve what you want is MAC specific

Comment: What is MAC?  Surely people aren’t still calling macOS “MAC”.

Answer (score 7):

If you are asking about macOS, the init system is called `launchd`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html

In IT always use most precise names as possible! For example MAC can mean Mandatory Access Control, which is something completely different.